# Поиск эквивалентных массивов

Tags: java, массивы, поиск, сравнение

Есть такая задачка:
на вход метода поступают `n` массивов строк, нужно определить дубликаты ли эти массивы игнорируя порядок и число объектов.
Например массивы `{"1", "z"}`
и `{"1", "z", "1", "z", "1", "z", "1"}` эквивалентны.
А `{"1", "z"}` и `{"0", "z"}` нет.
`{"1", "z"}` и `{"z"}` тоже нет.

Мое решение:

```java
public static boolean allStringSetsIdentical(String[][] sets) {
    boolean bool = true;
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    List<String> listOfStrings = null;
    for (String[] s : sets) {
        for (String str : s) {
            set.add(str);
        }
    }
    for (String[] s : sets) {
        listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(listOfStrings, s);
        for (String str : set) {
            if (!listOfStrings.contains(str)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Прошу подсказать, как сделать оптимальней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше решение работает, но медленно. `ArrayList.contains` делает линейный просмотр своего содержимого. Можно сказать что у вас квадратичный алгоритм в следующем смысле: если подать на вход два массива длиной `N`, то время работы будет `N^2`. Можно быстрее.

Заметим что два массива есть дубликаты, если множества, которые мы из них построим, равны. Так и надо поступить: из всех массивов строим множества и сравниваем их:

```
public static boolean allStringSetsIdentical(String[][] sets) {
    Set<String> first = null;
    for (String[] s : sets) {
        if (first == null) {
            first = makeSet(s);
        } else {
            if (!first.equals(makeSet(s))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Построить множество можно в одну строку: массив -> список -> множество. Но мы ведь за оптимальность? Тогда так:

```
public static Set<String> makeSet(String [] a) {
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String v : a) {
        s.add(v);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Построение и сравнение множеств делается за линейное время и быстрее нельзя. Так как строили множества руками, то памяти израсходовали необходимый минимум.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean allStringSetsIdentical(String[][] sets) {
    int maxSize = 0;
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (String[] s : sets) {
        if (s.length>maxSize && new HashSet(Arrays.asList(s)).size()>maxSize) maxSize=s.length;
        Collections.addAll(set, s);
    }
    return set.size()==maxSize;
}
```

Сет гарантирует уникальность элементов, следовательно, при добавлении всех элементов в него размер сета должен быть равен размеру самого большого массива, тогда и элементы эквиваленты.

Comment: валиться для случая {"a", "b"}, {"b", "b", "a"}, {"b", "a"} должно быть true

Comment: в условии не указали, что элементы массива могут повторяться. тогда надо немного модернизировать. код подправил

Comment: А если так? {"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}

Comment: результат будет false, длина сета тут 4, а длина максимального массива 2. насколько я понял условия, тут и должно быть false. можете еще добавить одно условие для ускорения кода

Comment: в условии у меня указано что массивы {"1", "z"} и {"1", "z", "1", "z", "1", "z", "1"} эквивалентны, это говорит о том, что элементы массива могут повторяться.

Comment: ну в любом случае это будет работать... этот код читается проще. время выполнения будет в среднем такое же. если хотите побороться за производительность, то можно попробовать вынести создание HashMap из условия за пределы цикла. потом просто очищать и добавлять новые элементы из массива. в любом случае я просто делюсь идеей, состоящей в том, что можно сравнить размеры коллекций с уникальными значениями, а не выполнять фактическое сравнение всех элементов. если правильно доработаете, то получите более производительный и легче читаемый код

Comment: `        String[][] s = {{"1", "z"}, {"z"}};
        System.out.println(allStringSetsIdentical(s));`

Печатает `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Попарно сравниваем массивы, проверяем вхождение элементов одного массива в другой массив:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr1 = {"1", "z"};
    String[] arr2 = {"1", "z", "1", "z", "1", "z", "1"};
    String[] arr3 = {"1", "z"};
    String[] arr4 = {"0", "z"};
    String[] arr5 = {"z"};

    System.out.println(containsAll(arr1, arr2)); // true
    System.out.println(containsAll(arr3, arr4)); // false
    System.out.println(containsAll(arr4, arr5)); // true
    System.out.println(containsAll(arr4, arr5, true)); // false
}
```

```java
// первый массив включает в себя второй массив,
// без учета дубликатов и порядка элементов
public static <T> boolean containsAll(T[] arr1, T[] arr2) {
    return containsAll(arr1, arr2, false);
}
```

```java
// первый массив включает в себя второй массив, и, если
// 'full == true', то первый массив состоит из элементов
// второго массива, без учета дубликатов и порядка элементов
public static <T> boolean containsAll(T[] arr1, T[] arr2, boolean full) {
    if (arr1 == null || arr2 == null)
        return false;

    // количество различных элементов в первом массиве
    long length1 = Arrays.stream(arr1).distinct().count();
    // количество различных элементов во втором массиве
    long length2 = Arrays.stream(arr2).distinct().count();

    if (length1 < length2 || full && length1 != length2)
        return false;

    return Stream.of(arr1, arr2)
            // выкидываем повторяющиеся элементы
            // из каждого массива и объединяем массивы
            .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a).distinct())
            // количество различных элементов в общем
            // массиве должно быть равно количеству
            // различных элементов в первом массиве
            .distinct().count() == length1;
}
```

---

См. [Проверить элементы одного массива на совпадения с элементами другого массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218154/420361)