# Проверить элементы одного массива на совпадения с элементами другого массива

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть два массива, которые содержат форматы в виде строки. К примеру:

```
formatsStorage [png, txt, doc]
formatsFile [jpg, txt, doc]
```

Элементы массивов могут располагаться в любой последовательности. Пример:

```
formatsStorage [doc, png, txt]
formatsFile [txt, jpg, doc]
```

Мне надо создать метод, который будет проверять все ли форматы из `formatsFile`, будут идентичны форматам из `formatsStorage`. Метод должен возвращать `true` если каждый формат из массива `formatsFile` будет находиться в массиве `formatsStorage`, а `false` возвращается если в массиве `formatsFile` будет находиться формат, которого нет в массиве `formatsStorage`.

Вот что у меня получилось пока сделать, но работает неправильно:

```java
public boolean checkFormatAll(List<File> filesFrom, Storage storageTo) throws Exception {
    if (filesFrom == null || storageTo == null)
        throw new Exception("Incoming data contains an error");

    String[] formatsStorage = storageTo.getFormatSupported().split(",");

    Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();

    for (File file : filesFrom) {
        strings.add(file.getFormat());
    }

    String[] formatsFile = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);

    System.out.println("Formats in Storage " + Arrays.toString(formatsStorage));
    System.out.println("Formats in file " + Arrays.toString(formatsFile));

    boolean format = true;
    int countStorage = 0;
    int countFile = 0;

    /*if (formatsFile.length == 1){
        for (String fileFormat : formatsFile){
            for (String storageFormat : formatsStorage){
                if (fileFormat != null && storageFormat != null && fileFormat.equals(storageFormat.trim())){
                    return true;
                }
                else format = false;
            }
        }
    }*/  //Не знаю, оставлять это в отдельном ифе или всё делать в одном ?

    for (String fileFormat : formatsFile) {
        if (fileFormat != null) {
            for (String storageFormat : formatsStorage) {
                if (storageFormat != null && fileFormat.equals(storageFormat.trim()) && formatsFile.length == 1) {
                    return true;
                } else format = false;

                if (storageFormat != null && !fileFormat.equals(storageFormat.trim()) && formatsFile.length != 1) {
                    continue;
                } else format = false;

                if (storageFormat != null && !fileFormat.equals(storageFormat.trim()) && formatsFile.length - 1 != countFile) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (storageFormat != null && fileFormat.equals(storageFormat.trim())) {
                    format = true;
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("Format in box storage - " + storageFormat + "; Line array Storage - " + countStorage);
                System.out.println("Format in box file - " + fileFormat + "; Line array File - " + countFile);

                countStorage++;
            }
            countFile++;
        }
    }
    return format;
}
```

Я понимаю, что надо сравнивать каждый элемент массива `formatsFile` с элементами массива `formatsStorage`. Для этого иду двойным циклом по элементам `formatsStorage`, но по всей видимости делаю ошибку в условиях сравнения. Помогите исправить ошибку.

Comment: вам надо сравнить, что это 2 одинаковых массива или что?

Comment: Komdosh, надо проверить содержатся ли все элементы массива `formatsFile`, в массиве `formatsStorage`. Если содержатся вернуть `true`, если нет хотя бы одного элемента, то вернуть` false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно преобразовать в списки и использовать метод `containsAll`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arr1[] = {"doc", "png", "jpg"};
    String arr2[] = {"png", "jpg", "doc"};
    String arr3[] = {"png", "jpg"};

    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(arr2);
    List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList(arr3);

    System.out.println(list2.containsAll(list1));
    System.out.println(list3.containsAll(list1));
}
```

Результат:

```
true
false
```

Comment: DaysLikeThis, не подходит Ваше решение. Вот такой пример:   
   `String arr1[] = {"doc", "png", "jpg"};
   String arr2[] = {"doc"}; `                                                                          Первый массив это форматы, которые поддерживает хранилище, а второй массив это формат файла. В этом случае должно быть `true`, а результат получается `false`.

Comment: @YuriiS list1.containsAll(list2)

Answer (score 0):

Проверяем полное вхождение в один массив элементов другого массива:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr1 = {"png", "txt", "doc"};
    String[] arr2 = {"jpg", "txt", "doc"};
    String[] arr3 = {"doc", "txt", "png"};
    String[] arr4 = {"png", "txt"};

    System.out.println(containsAll(arr1, arr2)); // false
    System.out.println(containsAll(arr1, arr3)); // true
    System.out.println(containsAll(arr3, arr4)); // true
    System.out.println(containsAll(arr3, arr4, true)); // false
}
```

```java
// первый массив включает в себя второй массив,
// без учета дубликатов и порядка элементов
public static <T> boolean containsAll(T[] arr1, T[] arr2) {
    return containsAll(arr1, arr2, false);
}
```

```java
// первый массив включает в себя второй массив, и, если
// 'full == true', то первый массив состоит из элементов
// второго массива, без учета дубликатов и порядка элементов
public static <T> boolean containsAll(T[] arr1, T[] arr2, boolean full) {
    if (arr1 == null || arr2 == null)
        return false;

    // количество различных элементов в первом массиве
    long length1 = Arrays.stream(arr1).distinct().count();
    // количество различных элементов во втором массиве
    long length2 = Arrays.stream(arr2).distinct().count();

    if (length1 < length2 || full && length1 != length2)
        return false;

    return Stream.of(arr1, arr2)
            // выкидываем повторяющиеся элементы
            // из каждого массива и объединяем массивы
            .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a).distinct())
            // количество различных элементов в общем
            // массиве должно быть равно количеству
            // различных элементов в первом массиве
            .distinct().count() == length1;
}
```