# Как задать массиву длину по заполнению?

Tags: java, массивы, for

Как задать массиву длину по заполняемым данным?
К примеру, генерируем случайные числа в массив `i` от `1` до `100`.
создаем цикл `for` и который перебирает эти числа в массиве `i` и если есть одинаковые числа `if (x == y)` то переводит эти данные в новый массив `K`

Проблема:
Новый массив `K` не знает количество совпавших чисел в массиве `i` - следовательно, нельзя изначально указать ему его размер. Как создать функцию, где при новом найденном элементе из массива `i` генерировалась новая ячейка в массиве `K`?

Comment: Т.е. если i[x] == i[y]( == i[z] и т.п., у нас же рандом, хоть все числа в массиве будут равны), то K[x] = i[x]?

Comment: Да. Но проблема в том, что массив K[x] = может быть до 10 элементов например. А нашло случайных одинаковых чисел 11.

Comment: Аааа, понятно. Используйте ArrayList, он динамический.                 
https://habr.com/post/128269/

Comment: принцип простой, изначально создаем массив определенной длины, например (25) и добавляем числа, пока не заполнится, если он будет полон, то создаем новый массив, с увеличением допустим n*2, и копируем туда данные, меняем ссылки. Такой же принцип используют динамические классы, либо применяют динамические структуры данных (односвязные списки, двусвязные списки) ArraList и ряд других классов

Comment: интересный вариант. Но тогда в последнем массиве, который к примеру создал 1000 элементов, может остаться 100 элементов с значением null. - Что собственно создаёт утечку памяти? @ЕвгенийФедак

Comment: Так ты проверь массив на null, и пересоздай массив с нужным размером.

Comment: после всех генераций, создай массив с размером полученных реальных элементов, и все) после этого сборщик мусора аккуратно почистит предыдущие пустые ссылки (сами ссылки на ничего не указывают, но занимают сколько то там байт)

Comment: Но вместо того что бы так *******, просто почитай про коллекции(я кидал ссылку выше) и используй их.

Comment: Я бы с радостью, но нужно писать без использования любых библиотек...

Comment: @ЮрийИва Коллекции это не библиотека. Это встроенный функционал в JDK.Очень полезная и удобная штука.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = new int[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr = extendArray(arr, i);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}

public static int[] extendArray(int[] arr, int value) {

    int[] newArray = new int[arr.length + 1];

    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, newArray, 0, arr.length);

    newArray[newArray.length - 1] = value;

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю не использовать функцию *System.arraycopy* из предложенного ранее ответа, вместо чего можно создать временный массив размером как исходный, а потом записать в него только нужные значения в результате чего мы еще можем и подсчитать количество этих значений - это и будет размером результирующего массива, а его элементами - те, что мы записали во временный. Похожее решение уже предлагал в комментариях @Евгений-Федак. 
Генерацию чисел я пропущу, реализацию проверки одинаковости элементов массива тоже лучше использовать свою. Предположим, что указанный массив уже будет подан на вход следующему методу:

```
public int[] getEqualDigits(int[] i) {
  int resultCount = 0; // количество элементов в результирующем массиве K
  int[] tempArray = new int[i.length]; // создаем временный массив размером как исходный
  for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) { // перебираем последовательно все элементы массива
      if (i[j] == i[j++]) { // условие отбора может быть любым, реализация взята из вопроса
          tempArray[resultCount] = i[j]; // элементом временного массива будет тот, который удовлетворяет нашим требованиям
          resultCount++;
      }
  }
  int[] K = new int[resultCount]; // создаем результирующий массив нужного нам размера, полученного на предыдущем шаге
  for (int n = 0; n < resultCount; n++) {
      K[n] = tempArray[n]; // последовательно перепишем элементы из временного массива в результирующий
  }
  return K;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Знать заранее количество элементов в массиве не обязательно, это зависит от алгоритма. Например, в данном случае количество элементов заранее не известно, и для данного алгоритма этим можно пренебречь:

```java
// создаем новый массив на 100 элементов
// и заполняем случайными числами от 1 до 100
int[] arr1 = IntStream.range(0, 100)
        .map(i -> (int) (1 + Math.random() * 100))
        .toArray();

// выкидываем из первого массива
// повторяющиеся элементы
// и получаем второй массив
int[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        .distinct()
        .toArray();

// количество элементов в первом
// массиве больше, чем во втором
System.out.println(arr1.length > arr2.length); // true
```

---

См. [Проверить элементы одного массива на совпадения с элементами другого массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218154/420361)